# Massaction to ship/notify/invoice + print label for labels (aka dymo or zebra)

Tags: orders, massaction

as an intermediate solution to waiting for logistics update I was tinkering about the following.

- Can we easily create a massaction to send all orders to a dymo (or any other) label printer in 1 go?
- or does a simple extension exist that can do this

So I have seen many mass actions extension like from xtento, amasty and probably also AW. But I have not seen one that also combines 'printing the label'

- So in the end it should do something like: 
  -- Massaction to ship/notify/invoice + print label for dymo/zebra in 1 go

Also 'printing the label' may also result in a simple PDf that we can send to the label printer ourselves

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> or does a simple extension exist that can do this

Yes, there are such extensions.

To print address labels to a Dymo printer: https://marketplace.magento.com/aquivemedia-aquivemedia-orderlabel.html

To print address labels to Zebra printers: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/zebra-order-address-direct-print-extension.html

*Disclaimer*: I am the developer of those extensions.